# How to force div to not go out from another

Tags: javascript, html, css

Problem is simple but seems I can't get over it, div called ".player" shouldn't be going out from div ".play-ground", it should be moving only in its yellow space. Next thing which I'm trying to achieve is that I want a div same size of the red one, showing up for some time, so that the user can catch it with the red one and after that he gets points otherwise doesn't. Is there any way to do it? And how make div disapear after being catched?

```js
var a = prompt("Provide nick");
while (a === "") {
  a = prompt("Provide nick");
}
document.write("<p>Nick: " + a + "</p>");

/* -------- */ 
var ground = document.getElementsByClassName('play-ground')[0];
var player = document.getElementsByClassName('player')[0];
var points = document.getElementsByClassName('numba')[0];
var thing = document.getElementsByClassName('thing-tocatch')[0];
document.onkeydown = move;

var lefts = 0;
var tops = 0;

function move(e) {
  console.log(e.keyCode);
  if (e.keyCode == 68) {
    lefts += 100;
    player.style.left = lefts + "px";
    points.innerHTML = lefts;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 65) {
    lefts -= 100;
    player.style.left = lefts + "px";
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 83) {
    tops += 100;
    player.style.top = tops + "px";
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 87) {
    tops -= 100;
    player.style.top = tops + "px";
  }

}
```

```css
.play-ground {
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  width: 800px;
  height: 700px;
}

.player {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.thing-tocatch {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 200px 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="game">
  <div class="points">
    <h3>Points: <span class="numba">0</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="play-ground">
    <div class="thing-tocatch">
    </div>

    <div class="player">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you use `position: absolute` you have no means to keep it inside the parent element in all circumstances.

Comment: Thank you for response. Yes I'm conscious about that, but how get over it?

Comment: you will need javascript to position the player elemene tinside the playgorund and if the position coords of player try to go outside the playground javascript should not allow it, byt forcing coords to be at most at the edges of the playground. In short you need javascript to move the player

Comment: How to get to the coordinates? You mean X and Y positions?

Comment: I tried to get it by selector.style.left and top, but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot write whole the app here, but I just want to show you some things.

1. Try to write your code: one action - one function. You can see as I did. I've splitted up your `move` function on two: `onKeyDown` and `movePlayer`. It will help you to support your code when the app will become bigger.
2. You should store states of your subjects. For example I've created object `Palyer` where I store his coords (you used for that two vars: `lefts` and `tops`). It will be better if you will implement the same for **all** subjects in your app. For example, the Player has props: width, height, x, y, color. The ground has props: width, height, color. The `thing` also should have props as for player. You should store these states as global variables, because you will need to use them in different functions.

Your questions:

- `Next thing which I'm trying to achieve is that I want a div same size of the red one, showing up for some time, so that the user can catch it with the red one and after that he gets points otherwise doesn't. Is there any way to do it?`. Your question contains answer. You need a function which will draw (`document.createElement('div')`) HTML element and after that you will be able to change its styles. **OR** you can create the `thing` before start (as you did with player) and keep it hidden (style `display: none;`)
- And how make div disapear after being catched? You can remove `thing` from DOM or change style to `display: none;`

I advice you to find similar apps to check how other developers implement similar things:

- [Pong Clone In JavaScript](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/pong-clone-in-javascript)
- [Snake Game in vanilla js](https://github.com/niklabh/vanilla-js-snake)

```js
var a = prompt("Provide nick");
while (a === "") {
  a = prompt("Provide nick");
}
document.write("<p>Nick: " + a + "</p>");

/* -------- */ 
var ground = document.getElementsByClassName('play-ground')[0];
var player = document.getElementsByClassName('player')[0];
var points = document.getElementsByClassName('numba')[0];
var thing = document.getElementsByClassName('thing-tocatch')[0];
document.onkeydown = onKeyDown;

var Player = {x: 0, y: 0};
var STEP = 100;

function onKeyDown (e) {
  console.log(e.keyCode);

  var x = Player.x;
  var y = Player.y;

  if (e.keyCode == 68) {
    x += STEP;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 65) {
    x -= STEP;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 83) {
    y += STEP;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 87) {
    y -= STEP;
  }

  movePlayer(x, y);
}

function movePlayer (x, y) {
  if (!isCoordsInsideGround(x, y)) return;

  Player.x = x || 0;
  Player.y = y || 0;

  player.style.left = Player.x + "px";
  player.style.top = Player.y + "px";
}

function isCoordsInsideGround (x, y) {
  if (x < 0 || ground.offsetWidth - STEP < x) {
    return false;
  }
  if (y < 0 || ground.offsetHeight - STEP < y) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```css
.play-ground {
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  width: 800px;
  height: 700px;
}

.player {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.thing-tocatch {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 200px 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="game">
  <div class="points">
    <h3>Points: <span class="numba">0</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="play-ground">
    <div class="thing-tocatch">
    </div>

    <div class="player">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped me a lot!